# How to avoid applied lazily Lists.transform in guava?

Tags: java, guava

```java
Map<String,Object> map = Maps.newHashMap();
map.put("test","123");
map.put("fuyou001","456");
map.put("id",145);
List<Map<String,Object>> list = Lists.newArrayList();
list.add(map);
Lists.transform(list, new Function<Map<String, Object>, Object>() {
  @Override
  public Object apply(@Nullable Map<String, Object> input) {
    System.out.println("test:" + input);
    return input;
  }
});
System.out.println(list);`
```

Console is not display "test...."

how to avoid applied lazily
I also try

```java
List<Map<String,Object>> newList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(list.size());
Collections.copy(newList,list);
```

but not effect

Answer (score 19):

`Function`s in general should not have side effects; that's  your real problem.

That said, if you insist on applying the transformation immediately, do a copy: `Lists.newArrayList(Lists.transform(list, function))`.

Comment: if i don't use Lists.newArrayList(Lists.transform(list, function)).when the function will be fired?

Comment: When you actually iterate over or query the list.

Answer (score 4):

Using an ImmutableList will force the values to be computed eagerly, and thus, no need for an extra copy afterwards. This is perhaps a more elegant solution:

```
list = ImmutableList.copyOf(Lists.transform(list, 
  new Function<Map<String, Object>, Object>() {
  @Override
  public Object apply(@Nullable Map<String, Object> input) {
    System.out.println("test:" + input);
    return input;
  }
}));
System.out.println(list);`
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement Louis' answer, you're using `Lists.transform()` as if it modified the original `list`, like `Collections.sort()`. It doesn't.

You have to use the return value of `Lists.transform()` to see something happen, keeping in mind that it's a *view* which gets evaluated each and every time you call it. So if you need to use the result several times, as Louis said, do a copy in a new `List` (`ArrayList`, `ImmutableList`, etc.).